# Selecting one normal from a tensor based on another random variable in TensorFlow Probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, probability, tensorflow-probability

I'm attempting to select a single sample from a range of Normal distributions based upon the output of a categorical distribution, however can't seem to come up with quite the right way to do it. Using something along the lines of:

```
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionSequential([
        tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=[0, 0, 1/2, 1/2]),
        lambda c: tfp.distributions.Normal([0, 1, -10, 30], 1)[..., c]
    ])
```

Returns exactly what I want for the single case, however if I want multiple samples at once this breaks (as c becomes a numpy array rather than an integer. Is this possible and if so, how should I go about it?

(I also attempted using OneHotCategorical and multiplying but that didn't work at all!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, if you don't want to use `MixtureSameFamily` as Brian suggests:

```
tfp.distributions.JointDistributionSequential([
        tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=[0, 0, 1/2, 1/2]),
        lambda c: tfp.distributions.Normal(tf.gather([0., 1, -10, 30], c), 1)
    ])
```

Note I needed to add a `.` to the locs in the gather to avoid a dtype error.

Here, what we end up doing is

1. drawing `n` samples from the `Categorical`
2. constructing a batch of `n` `Normal`s, whose locs are obtained by indexing `n` times into the 4-vector of locs
3. sampling from that `n`-batch of `Normal`s.

The previous approach doesn't work because `Distribution` slicing doesn't support this kind of ["fancy indexing"](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html) It would be cool if we did! TF doesn't support it in general, for [reasons](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638).

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I'm aiming for in the end, as I also wanted to know which categorical had been selected, which I couldn't work out how to do with @Brian-patton 's (also very helpful) answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's another [distribution](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MixtureSameFamily?version=nightly) for that:

```py
tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
  mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=[0, 0, .5, .5]),
  components_distribution=tfd.Normal([0, 1, -10, 30], 1))
```